# Odroid-XU4 Android full-screen portrait orientation

Tags: android, orientation, odroid

I want to install an Android OS to an Odroid-XU4 device and connect it to a vertical touchscreen through HDMI. I want the content be displayed as portrait and fit the screen.

I installed 4.4.4, 6.0 (Cyanogenmod 13.0) and 7.1(Lineage 14.1) android images to the Odroid. By default, all of them display the screen as landscape , so I must configure the OS to get it displayed as portrait.

I first used AndroidUtility (a tool included in the OS image) and set HDMI orientation as portrait. The screen is displayed great (portrait and full screen) with the 4.4.4 OS image. Unfortunately, 4.4.4 OS doesn't work for me because the device has to be a COSU and this needs 6.0 or above OS version.

But using AndroidUtility , the screen is displayed like this in both 6.0 and 7.1 OSs:

[image]

After looking it over forums, blogs... I found out that the solution should be editting these lines in OS build.prop config file:

```
persist.demo.hdmirotation=portrait
ro.sf.hwrotation=270 (I have tried 90 too)
windowsmgr.support_rotation_270=true
```

Doing this, 7.1 OS version looks as portait and fills all the screen... but it's displayed upside down.

And 6.0 OS version looks not only turned, but also cropped:

[image]

How can I get it displayed as portrait and full-screen?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue using LineageOS from [here](https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=94&t=23911)

([Source](https://oph.mdrjr.net/voodik/5422/ODROID-XU3/Android/lineage-14.1/Alpha-1.3_14.12.17/))

I ran the update to the most recent release from the ODROID Utility and it changed the "HDMI Landscape / HDMI Portrait 90+270" to a straight 0, 90, 180, 270. To change it required a reboot.

([Fetched](https://oph.mdrjr.net/voodik/5422/ODROID-XU3/Android/lineage-14.1/Alpha-1.6_17.02.18/))

[image: ODROID XU4 on an ELO 32" Touchscreen]

Answer (score 1):

All Android devices manages the screen sizes in the same way, so that has nothing to do with your android odroid, unless you have forced to be in landscape, and your monitor source is with a portrait orientation.

[image]You just need to adjust your screen display monitor source orientation usually is using your screen menu, `

```
Menu->Display->(Horizontal or Vertical)
```